# Assigning jobs in a functional style

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm new to F# and functional programming in general (coming from an object oriented background). I just wanted to get some criticism on an algorithm for assigning jobs to crew members. I want to be as functional as possible and avoid loops and mutable state. Here is what I've come up with.

```
let rec AssignJobs crewMembers jobs jobAssignments = 
    let AssignJob job crewMembers = 
        let bestCrewMember = crewMembers |> Seq.sortWith crewMemberComparison
                                         |> Seq.head
        {CrewMember = bestCrewMember; Job = job}

    match jobs with
    | job :: remainingJobs -> 
        let jobAssignment = AssignJob job crewMembers            
        let remainingCrewMembers = crewMembers |> Seq.filter ((<>)jobAssignment.CrewMember)            
        AssignJobs remainingCrewMembers remainingJobs (jobAssignments @ [jobAssignment])
    | [] -> jobAssignments
```

Assume that `crewMemberComparison` is working for this review. I'm more concerned about whether I have a good approach to managing the `crewMembers`, `jobs` and `jobAssignments` sequences.

I don't like how I have to invoke this with an empty list i.e.

`let assignedJobs = AssignJobs crewMembers jobs []`

Is there another way? Is recursion the best solution at all (presuming I'm not allowed to loop)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't like how I have to invoke this with an empty list i.e.
>
> ```
> let assignedJobs = AssignJobs crewMembers jobs []
> ```
>
> Is there another way? Is recursion the best solution at all (presuming I'm not allowed to loop)?

The 'empty list' initiation is pretty standard in F#. The nice thing about it is if you load a list of currently assigned jobs from a data-source (database, API, etc.) you can seed the function with the current assignments.

Recursion is perfectly fine here, and in fact it's the route I would go to solve this issue. That said, I would actually consider an `unfold` as well, which would remove the empty-list requirement.

Basically, `unfold` takes some seed data (here it would be the `crewMembers` and `jobs` lists) and it creates a sequence/list/array from that seed data. (It's the opposite of `fold`: whereas `fold` creates a single result from a list, even if that's another list, `unfold` takes a single result and creates the original list.)

With regard to your current method, I have minimal comments. This is quite idiomatic F#, and follows most of the standard themes we use.

> ```
> let AssignJob job crewMembers = 
>     let bestCrewMember = crewMembers |> Seq.sortWith crewMemberComparison
>                                      |> Seq.head
>     {CrewMember = bestCrewMember; Job = job}
> ```

I'm not a big fan of your formatting, but beyond that I see no issues here. Personally, I would break it down as follows:

```
let AssignJob job crewMembers = 
    let bestCrewMember = 
        crewMembers
        |> Seq.sortWith crewMemberComparison
        |> Seq.head
    { CrewMember = bestCrewMember; Job = job }
```

(I don't like leaving unnecessary whitespace on the left — makes it harder to find the code you need to see.)

Also, I would name that `assignJob` as is normal F# parlance for function names.

Lastly, you *could* take advantage of `Seq.exept` instead of `Seq.filter ((<>) ...)`, but you need to instantiate an extra list or array to do that, so I'm not sure if it's worth it.